# Where to find the column "Decadence Now", which is cited in _Garbology_

Tags: waste, internet

My favorite book about garbage is [*Garbology*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1583335234), by US journalist Edward Humes.  It discusses garbage, what we do with it, and better ways to deal with it.

The book is about a decade old, but still relevant today.  According to WorldCat.org, ~1,500 public library systems worldwide still own at least one copy of the book. Some of these library systems may have dozens of branches and may hold multiple copies.

On page 181 of the book, Humes cites a magazine column by garbage archaeologist and anthropology professor William Rathje:

- Rathje, William. "Decadence now." Beyond the Pail. *MSW management: the journal for municipal solid waste professionals*. Volume 11, issue 1.

Where can I find this column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was perhaps rather tricky to find, but I did find a copy of the column using the Internet Archive Wayback Machine.

You may [read the column here](http://web.archive.org/web/20021113165734/http://www.forester.net/msw_0101_beyond.html).

Comment: LOL "Toronto Metroplex" - also describing a Canadian project as America's anything.